# SQL Group sort by date

Tags: sql, group-by, distinct, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table that resembles the following:

```
id
type
created (date).
```

What I want is to return the most recently created item of each type. So it will return one item (most recent) for each type.

E.G.

`id:1   type:A   created:2011`

`id:2   type:A   created:2008`

`id:3   type: B   created:2009`

`id:4   type: B   created:2010`

This will return with record id 1 and 4.

Comment: There is a tag for this type of (very often asked) queries: **`[greatest-n-per-group]`**. Click on the tag or under the **Related** header, on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works using a self join

```
select T1.* from table t1 LEFT JOIN table t2 
ON t1.type = t2.type and t1.created < t2.created
where t2.id is null
```